# How to vertically align in img inside a span?

Tags: css

I am facing a problem:

I need to vertically align an `img` inside a `span`. I first thought on using `vertical-align: middle` but it doesn't properly do it.

I searched on StackOverflow and multiple people suggested using flexbox, but I cannot use it in this case since the line needs to still wrap text like shown here :

[image]

What kind of CSS voodoo is there to solve this ?

EDIT: [Here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/nanokz/pen/abVmZYe), by using `vertical-align: middle` and Inspecting the element I can see that the bottom `line` is 1.45px taller than it should be, when I remove the images it becomes 32px as intended.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see you `HTML`?

Comment: Hi, yes I just added the CodePen as an edit to the post

Comment: I just checked your code in firefox and its seems to be working.

Comment: vertical-align works, kinda. The image shouldn't spill out the limits, yet it does by 1.45px. When messages come in, the text just bounces constantly

Answer (score 0):

Try to add like this in span

```
span {
display:flex;
justify-content: center; 
align-items:center;
}
```

align-items is used for vertical alignment. If you had given any id to that span , you can use that.

Comment: Unfortunetly it messes up the layout of the message, I need it to be inline

Answer (score 0):

## hope this [pen](https://codepen.io/neptotech/full/ZEapBqa) helps

> [this *pure css* library helps you align easily *if you feel* **layout is messed up**](https://github.com/ItsJonQ/hstack-vstack-css/blob/master/src/styles.css)

## main code

```css
    display: flex;/*supports trick*/
    flex-direction: column;/*trick*/
```

- `flex-direction` `column` makes it stack vertically one below another